# JS throwing uncaught syntax error on frist line no matter what

Tags: syntax-error

```
//Any frist Line
const timeEl = document.getElementById("time");
const dateEl = document.getElementById("date");
const currentInfoEl = document.getElementById("current-info");
const timeZone = document.getElementById("time-zone");
const location = document.getElementById("location");
const forecast = document.getElementById("forecast");
const currentTempEl = document.getElementById("current-info");
```

In this file I have  just declarled some const. But no matter what is one the Frist line it is showing
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'location' has already been declared**

Even If the frist Line is a comment is Showing the same eror.

I tried commenting the Frist line and `console.log("hello");` run just this code. Still the error is in the frist line.

Comment: If running just `console.log("hello");` is producing that error, then you're not running the code you think you are. Is your IDE maybe configured to run a different file than the one you're editing? Or maybe you need to save your changes being running?

Answer (score -1):

Still can not say what the problem was. I deleted the js file and created a new one and it worked.